# Linearity property of the Poisson distribution-- is it unique?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

The family of Poisson distributions (parametrised by its mean) has an interesting 'linearity' property:

> $$\mathrm{Poisson}(x) + \mathrm{Poisson(y)} \sim \mathrm{Poisson(x+y)}$$

...meaning that the sum of two **independent random** variables drawn from poisson distributions with means $x$ and $y$ is itself distributed as a Poisson variable, with mean $(x+y)$.

1. Do any other probability distribution families have the same property?
2. Are there similar distribution families $D(a)$ on other binary operations $\odot$?
   $$\text{i.e.} \qquad D(a) \odot D(b) \sim D(a \odot b)$$

Comment: ... sum of two *independent* random variables ...

Comment: @StefanHansen already implied by the phrasing *drawn from poisson distributions with means...* but ok.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regaring  question 1), there is the class  [infinitely divisible distributions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)) (for a textbook reference taking this further to stochastic processes, see [Sato 1999](https://books.google.ca/books/about/L%C3%A9vy_Processes_and_Infinitely_Divisible.html?id=tbZPLquJjSoC&redir_esc=y)). However, the parameter in question is not necessarily the mean like for the Poisson distribution.

The Gamma distribution, for example, belongs to this class. The sum of independent Gamma RVs all having equal scale but potentially different shape parameters is again Gamma with the same scale and the shape parameter given by the sum of the individual shapes. The chi-square distribution is another example. And all stable distributions belong to this class (see also [this thread for infinitely divisible but not stable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1718196/278945)). The normal distribution is a stable distribution.

**However**, the class of infinitely divisible distributions does not fully characterize the class satisfying the "linearity property". Rather, it is a subclass because two independent binomial distributions with the same success probability, for example, also satisfy the "linearity property" (proof by multiplication of their moment generating functions) but a binomial distribution is not infinitely divisible (as a binomial cannot be expressed as a sum of an *arbitrary* number of binomials, whereby I exclude degenerate binomials in the sense of having a success probability of zero).

Regarding question 2), as maybe a "cheap" example I consider multiplication as the operator and the exp of an infinitely divisible RV as distribution:

$exp(X) * exp(Y) = exp(X+Y). $

If $X$ and $Y$ are normals, then we get the log-normal example, mentioned in Bryden C's answer.

EDIT-log: I added the paragraph "However, the class of..." and a reference to Sato.

Comment: Hello, as stated in the bounty I am looking for an "answer from a reputable source". E.g. mathematical literature, or a book that goes into greater detail and more thorough explanation than a Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thank you Elsa, I would like to award the full bounty but I don't know if that's possible now. I cannot see how. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Myridium thank you. I am happy with any part of the bounty. Maybe by nature of the question, the bounty must be split on two individuals, so that sum of bounties is then again a bounty ;)

Answer (score 1):

There are many distributions with similar properties. In general, given the independent random variables $X,Y$ who have [moment generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) $M_x(t),M_y(t)$, we have that if, for given constants $a,b$

$$
S = aX + bY
$$

then the moment generating function of $S$ is given by

$$
M_S(t) = M_x(at) \cdot M_y(bt)
$$

this result can be generalized for $n$ independent random variables.

For example, if $X \sim N(\mu_x, \sigma_x^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_y, \sigma_y^2)$, then their MGFs are

$$
M_x(t) = \exp(\mu_x t + \sigma_x^2t^2/2) \qquad M_y(t) = \exp(\mu_y t + \sigma_y^2t^2/2)
$$

hence, if $S = X + Y$

$$
M_S(t) = M_x(t) = \exp(\mu_x t + \sigma_x^2t^2/2)\exp(\mu_y t + \sigma_y^2t^2/2) = \exp((\mu_x + \mu_y) t + (\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)t^2/2)
$$

thus $S \sim N(\mu_x + \mu_y,\sigma_x^2 + \sigma_y^2)$.

Some other distributions that follow similar properties that I can think of include the Binomial, Negative Binomial, and Gamma distributions.

As for other binary operations, for the multiplication of two random variables, I can think of the [lognormal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution).

Comment: Hello, as stated in the bounty I am looking for an "answer from a reputable source". E.g. mathematical literature, or a book that goes into greater detail and more thorough explanation than a Wikipedia article.